# Extracting numbers from a paragraph/text in C language

Tags: c, visual-studio

back here with an extension to my program. I am needed to extract numbers from this specific text,

“I have the amount of **principal** of RM **5000** for investing into your bank fixed-deposit
account for a **compound ratio** of **3** months with an annual **interest rate** of **3.5%**, I
would like to know/ask/enquire the balance after the **duration/period** of **5** years.
Please kindly generate a report/portfolio for me from **year** **1 to 5**.”

The numbers I need to extract are 5000, 3, 3.5%, 5 and 1 to 5. Oh! It's in part 8 of my IF function, just thought it would be helpful for me to upload my whole code. I have tried using strtok, strncmp, strstr, strtol but I can't seem to get it right.

Could use all of your help. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int mark = 0;
    int max = 1;
    while (mark <= max)
    {
        char Pa[20], ra[20], na[20], ta[20], Ba[20], ta1[20], ra1[20], na1[20], Ba1[20], Pa1[20];
        char Pa2[20], ra2[20], na2[20], ta2[20], Ba2[20];
        double array1[5];
        char S[20], E[20];
        char text[100];
        int Start, End;
        int StartLimit;
        int option;
        char o[20];
        double P, r, n, t, B;
        double P2, r2, n2, t2, B2;
        float n1 = 1, P1, r1, B1;
        int t1;
        int limit = 1;
        int counter = 0, result = 1;
        float answer = 0, difference = 0.1;
        int count = 0;

        printf("Welcome! Brought to you by Yeo Joel Jian Wei, 20203236\n");
        printf("What would you like to do today?\n");
        printf("1) Calculate Balance\n");
        printf("2) Calculate Principal\n");
        printf("3) Calculate Interest Rate\n");
        printf("4) Calculate Compound Ratio\n");
        printf("5) Calculate Number of Years\n");
        printf("6) Generate report for given year interval\n");
        printf("7) Compare two accounts\n\n");
        printf("8) Enter your own request\n\n");

        printf("Choose option 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8\n");
        scanf("%s", o);

        if (isdigit(o[0]) != 0)
        {
            option = atof(o);
            mark = mark + 10;
            if (option >= 1 && option <= 8)
            {
                for (int marker = 0; marker <= limit; marker++)
                {
                    if (option == 1)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Principal, P = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Interest Rate, r = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Compound Ratio, n = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Number of Years, t = ");
                        scanf("%s", ta);

                        if (isdigit(Pa[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ta[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P = atof(Pa);
                            r = atof(ra);
                            n = atof(na);
                            t = atof(ta);
                            B = P * pow(1 + (r / n), n * t);
                            printf("\nBalance, B is %.2lf\n", B);
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 2)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Interest Rate, r = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Compound Ratio, n = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Number of Years, t = ");
                        scanf("%s", ta);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Balance, B = ");
                        scanf("%s", Ba);

                        if (isdigit(Ba[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ta[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            B = atof(Ba);
                            r = atof(ra);
                            n = atof(na);
                            t = atof(ta);
                            P = ((pow(n, (n * t)) * B) / (pow((n + r), (n * t))));
                            printf("\nPrincipal, P is %.2lf\n", P);
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 3)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Compound Ratio, n = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Number of Years, t = ");
                        scanf("%s", ta);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Principal, P = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Balance, B = ");
                        scanf("%s", Ba);

                        if (isdigit(Pa[0]) != 0 && isdigit(Ba[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ta[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P = atof(Pa);
                            B = atof(Ba);
                            n = atof(na);
                            t = atof(ta);
                            r = (n * (pow(B, (1 / (n * t))) - pow(P, ((1 / (n * t)))))) / pow(P, (1 / (n * t)));
                            printf("\nInterest Rate, r is %.3lf\n", r);
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 4)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Number of Years, t: ");
                        scanf("%s", ta1);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Interest Rate, r: ");
                        scanf("%s", ra1);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Principal, P: ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa1);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Balance, B: ");
                        scanf("%s", Ba1);

                        if (isdigit(Pa1[0]) != 0 && isdigit(Ba1[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra1[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ta1[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P1 = atof(Pa1);
                            B1 = atof(Ba1);
                            r1 = atof(ra1);
                            t1 = atoi(ta1);
                            while (fabs(B1 - answer) >= difference)
                            {
                                answer = P1 * pow((1 + r1 / n1), (n1 * t1));
                                n1 += 0.005;
                                counter += 1;
                                if (counter > 1e6) {
                                    printf("\nCompound Ratio, n can't be found\n");
                                    result = 0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (result = 1)
                            {
                                printf("\nCompound Ratio, n is %.0f\n", n1);
                            }
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 5)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Compound Ratio, n = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Interest Rate, r = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Principal, P = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Balance, B = ");
                        scanf("%s", Ba);

                        if (isdigit(Pa[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0 && isdigit(Ba[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P = atof(Pa);
                            B = atof(Ba);
                            n = atof(na);
                            r = atof(ra);
                            t = ((log10(B / P) / log10(1 + r / n)) / n);
                            printf("\nNumber of Years, t is %.2lf\n", t);
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 6)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of Principal, P = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Interest Rate, r = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Compound Ratio, n = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Start Year, S = ");
                        scanf("%s", S);
                        printf("\nEnter value of End Year, E = ");
                        scanf("%s", E);

                        printf("\nYear\tPrincipal\tInterest Rate\tCompound Ratio\tBalance");

                        if (isdigit(S[0]) != 0 && isdigit(E[0]) != 0 && isdigit(Pa[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P = atof(Pa);
                            B = atof(Ba);
                            n = atof(na);
                            r = atof(ra);
                            Start = atoi(S);
                            End = atoi(E);
                            StartLimit = Start;

                            while (StartLimit <= End)
                            {
                                array1[0] = Start;
                                array1[1] = P;
                                array1[2] = r;
                                array1[3] = n;
                                B = P * pow(1 + (r / n), n * Start);
                                array1[4] = B;
                                printf("\n%.0lf\t%.2lf\t%.3lf\t\t%.2lf\t\t%.2lf\n", array1[0], array1[1], array1[2], array1[3], array1[4]);
                                Start++;
                                StartLimit++;

                            }
                            marker = marker + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\n\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 7)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter value of First Acccount's Principal, P1 = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa);
                        printf("\nEnter value of First Acccount's Interest Rate, r1 = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra);
                        printf("\nEnter value of First Acccount's Compound Ratio, n1 = ");
                        scanf("%s", na);
                        printf("\nEnter value of First Acccount's Number of Years, t1 = ");
                        scanf("%s", ta);

                        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                        printf("\nEnter value of Second Acccount's Principal, P2 = ");
                        scanf("%s", Pa2);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Second Acccount's Interest Rate, r2 = ");
                        scanf("%s", ra2);
                        printf("\nEnter value of Second Acccount's Compound Ratio, n2 = ");
                        scanf("%s", na2);

                        if (isdigit(Pa[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ta[0]) != 0 && isdigit(Pa2[0]) != 0 && isdigit(ra2[0]) != 0 && isdigit(na2[0]) != 0)
                        {
                            P = atof(Pa);
                            r = atof(ra);
                            n = atof(na);
                            t = atof(ta);
                            B = P * pow(1 + (r / n), n * t);
                            P2 = atof(Pa2);
                            r2 = atof(ra2);
                            n2 = atof(na2);

                            t2 = ((log10(B / P2)) / (n2 * log10(1 + (r2 / n2))));
                            int i = (int)t2;
                            double result = (t2 - i) * 12;
                            if (result > 11.5)
                            {
                                printf("\nIt will take %d years and %.1lf months for Account 2 to acquire the same balance as Account 1, which is %.2lf\n", i, result, B);
                                marker = marker + 10;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("\nIt will take %d years and %.1lf months for Account 2 to acquire the same balance as Account 1, which is %.2lf\n", i, result, B);
                                marker = marker + 10;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
                            marker = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (option == 8)
                    {
                        printf("Enter your request.\n");
                        scanf("%s", &text);

                        marker = marker + 10;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n\n");
                mark = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (isdigit(o[0]) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n\n");
            mark = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joel, just to check if you are still reading this, I can help you, but first you should edit your question and provide a [mcve] with what you tried and failed. If you reply to a comment be sure to add @ followed by the user name of the person you are answering to, so that he gets a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the **sscanf** function.
It reads a formatted input from a char pointer.